# Applet AccessControlException in "business" method only

Tags: java, permissions, applet, restrictions, accesscontrolexception

I have an applet, that does file signing using a certificate from smartcard, that means several extra permissions needed to get it working: loading .dll as file on local machine, creating temp files etc.

All involved jars are signed and started as Java Web Start.

I find confusing, that when full logic is called from init() method, everything works fine:

```
public void init() {
    try {
        File directory = new File("C:/Temp");
        deployPKCS11Library(directory);

        testFullCycleOnApplet("C:/somefile.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If I will take `testFullCycleOnApplet` out of my init method and run it on button click after initialization, I will get:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.io.tmpdir" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)...
```

Does init method has more rights to perform restricted stuff ?
In JNLP file I have set

```
<security>
    <all-permissions /> 
</security>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is dedicated to many programming languages. Please add an appropriate language, framework or technology tag to your questions to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a ready answer to this question :

[Does AccessController.doPrivileged give JavaScript threads the permissions of the signed Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632283/does-accesscontroller-doprivileged-give-javascript-threads-the-permissions-of-th)

The main reason I had this different security profile for separate function call is fact that it got invoked from JavaScript!
This way it works well, not that is is a nice way to do it - most probably you would do some particular things in privileged context.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void testFullCycleOnApplet(final String fileName){
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {
            doFullCycleOnApplet(fileName);
            return null; // nothing to return
        }
    });
}
```